# Numpy, simple formulation to concatenate integers and ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently switching from Matlab to Python and a rather simple action in Matlab  seems pretty tricky in Python.

Given

```
A = array([0, 0, 0, 0])
B = 1
C = 2
D = array([3, 4])
```

I only found this way to get the following E:

```
E = np.vstack((A, np.hstack((np.array([B, C]), D))))
```

In Matlab, the same E is simply obtained writing:

```
E = [A; B, C, D]
```

Is there any simpler way to get E in Python?

Comment: You can use Python syntax to build a 2D list and then `array` it, like `E = np.array([A, [B, C], D])`. That has a small cost (building a couple of tiny lists), but it's unlikely to mattr

Comment: Although if you're trying to concatenate `[B, C]` to `D` that would require `np.array([A, [B, C, *D]])`, which has more of a cost (it has to unpack all of `D` into a plain Python list—which is fine if `D` is two values, but maybe not if it's two billion…)

Comment: Well MATLAB equivalent domain would be `np.matrix`. So, convert those inputs to matrices with `np.matrix()` and simply use : `np.bmat('A; B,C,D')`.

Comment: You will some things are much simpler/concise in Python.

Comment: @abarnert This * operator in front of D was the thing I didn't know then. Do you know other operators useful for list/array manipulations?

Comment: @RobinTournemenne The `*` in `[B, C, *D]` is "iterable unpacking". It's often called the "splat operator", but it's not really an operator, and "splat" doesn't appear anywhere in the docs. The tutorial covers its use [in function call arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and [in assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), but you can also use it inside a list display.

Comment: For full details of exactly where you can and can't use `*` the only recourse is to read [the reference docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) or [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). But usually, if it makes unambiguous sense, you can do it. Here, `[B, C, *D]` could only mean you want a list composed of B, and C, and all of the elements of whatever D is, so that's what it means.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who transitioned from MATLAB to Python just over a year ago, you're not alone in going through the syntax learning curve. Once you've worked through a few examples, you start to get the hang of it.

As @abarnert mentioned in the comments, simply instantiate your arrays as you have done:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
B = 1
C = 2
D = np.array([3, 4])
```

Then you can construct your output matrix as follows:

```
E = np.matrix([A, [B, C, *D]])
```

Which gives:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 2 3 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This matrix function will be useful for sure!

Comment: I just realized that  `np.matrix` isn't needed here.  `np.array` works just as well.

Comment: You're right, `np.matrix` is not needed here, but I think it lends itself to understanding how Python handles an array of arrays in contrast to MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

Since `numpy` works within Python, it can't customize the syntax.

In Octave:

```
>> A = [0,0,0,0];
>> B=1;
>> C=2;
>> D=[3,4];
>> E = [A; B,C,D]
E =
   0   0   0   0
   1   2   3   4
```

Note that `B` and `C` are (1,1) matrices.  MATLAB doesn't have true scalars.

`np.block` gives some of the same notational compactness:

```
In [183]: A = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
     ...: B = 1
     ...: C = 2
     ...: D = np.array([3, 4])
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [184]: np.block([[A],[B,C,D]])
Out[184]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Under the covers `block` does a recursive concatenate.

Your `np.vstack([A, np.hstack((B,C,D))])` also uses `concatenate`:

`hstack` first makes sure all its inputs are at least 1d.  So it has to turn `B` (scalar) into `np.array(B)`

```
In [195]: np.concatenate((np.array([B]),np.array([C]),D))
Out[195]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

`vstack` makes sure its inputs are at least 2d.

```
In [197]: np.concatenate((A[None,:], Out[195][None,:]),axis=0)
Out[197]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

MATLAB probably has to do lot of the same kinds of conversions under the covers (though inherently everything starts as 2d).  But it uses its own syntax parser.

---

If we start off with 2d arrays, the nested concatenates are are simpler:

```
In [198]: A = np.array([[0,0,0,0]])
In [199]: B = np.array([[1]])
In [200]: C = np.array([[2]])
In [201]: D = np.array([[3,4]])

In [203]: np.concatenate((A, np.concatenate((B,C,D),axis=1)), axis=0)
Out[203]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

As noted in the other answer, the `np.matrix` subclass was provided years ago as a way of giving `numpy` a MATLAB feel, with inherently 2d arrays, and some notation similarities.

---

Playing around a bit more, I find that I don't actually need either `block` or `np.matrix`.  `np.array` works:

```
In [222]: A = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
     ...: B = 1
     ...: C = 2
     ...: D = np.array([3, 4])
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [223]: np.array([A,[B,C,*D]])
Out[223]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

The `*D` is Python syntax, not something special to `numpy`:

```
In [224]: [B,C,*D]
Out[224]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [225]: [A,[B,C,*D]]
Out[225]: [array([0, 0, 0, 0]), [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

`np.array` takes that last list and turns it into an array, the same as it would with `np.array([[0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4]])`.